# Are tabls and tabularx not compatible?

Tags: tables, tabularx, incompatibility, tabls

The following MWE does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabls}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc>{\arraybackslash}}

1&2&3&4\\
1&2&3&4\\
1&2&3&4\\
1&2&3&4

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/temp/test-tablespace2.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
(C:\miktex\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\miktex\tex\latex\base\size10.clo)) (C:\miktex\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty
(C:\miktex\tex\latex\tools\array.sty)) (C:\miktex\tex\latex\tabls\tabls.sty)
(C:\temp\test-tablespace2.aux)
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@argtabularcr [#1]->\ifnum \z@ =`{\fi }
                                        &\omit {\ifnum \z@ =`}\fi \global \a...
l.10 1
      &2&3&4\\
?
```

I have tried `\tabularnewline`instead of `\\`, but it did not help. Neither did using `>{\arraybackslash}` in the last column.

What is wrong?

*EDIT*: 
I tried different loading order as Werner mentions in the comment, but when I loaded `tabularx` last, the commands I was interested in:

```
\setlength\tablinesep{5pt} 
\setlength\arraylinesep{5pt} 
\setlength\extrarulesep{5pt}
\hline[extra]
```

do not have any effect. I assumed `tabularx`redefined some commands, therefore I loaded `tabls` last.

Comment: You can replicate this problem by only using [this code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UI2mI.png). It has nothing to do with [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), but with [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) (loaded by `tabularx`). As such, if you change the load order (`tabls,array`, or `tabls,tabularx`) it compiles. Of course, this may result in some functionality loss. Are you just interested in the compatibility, or something else as well?

Comment: Both `tabls` and `array` redefine `\@array`, so they fight each other. No way they can be made compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching the loading order is no avail, because both packages redefine `\@array` (`tabularx` loads `array` which does the redefinition) in incompatible ways and there's no hope to make them live together.

Answer (score 2):

I want to point that `cellspace` has the same functionality as `tabls` and is compatible with tabularx and array. It defines minimal vertical distances between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and between the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell. You have to prefix column qualifiers with the letter `S`(or `C` if you use `SIunitx`). Illustration with a 4×4 magic square:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, cellspace}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\texttt{With the S prefix from cellspace: }\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{0.333\linewidth}{|*{4}{S{X}|}}
\hline
4 & 14 & 15 & 1\\
\hline
19 & 7 & 6 & 12\\
\hline
5 & 11 & 10 & 8\\
\hline
16 & 2 & 3 & 13\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\vskip1cm
\noindent\texttt{Plain X columns: }\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{0.333\linewidth}{|*{4}{X|}}
\hline
4 & 14 & 15 & 1\\
\hline
19 & 7 & 6 & 12\\
\hline
5 & 11 & 10 & 8\\
\hline
16 & 2 & 3 & 13\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative! In my case, using the `S` as in `\begin{tabular}{Sr Sl l}` had **no effect**. I found out that I had to rename the command `S` using the `column` option of the package, namely, `\usepackage[column=W]{cellspace}` and then use  `W` instead of  `S` in the tabular environment, as in `\begin{tabular}{Wr Wl l}`.  Then it worked! Apparently there was a conflict definition with another package.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: Probably you also loaded `siunitx `, whch defines the `S`columntype. Also,  I wouldn't use the letter W, because in (comparatively) recent versions of `array`the  `W` and `w` column types are defined. As far as I know, the letters Q and O are not used anywhere.