# Add vertical space between \hline and the row consisting of only \multicolumn (without using \midrule)

Tags: tables, spacing, multicolumn

I want to add vertical space between `\hline`'s and the rows consisting of only `\multicolumn`. I do not want to use `\midrule`.

The answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202678/add-space-between-hline-and-superscript-without-affecting-any-other-spacing) do not work in case of `\multicolumn`.

[image]

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Method A}\\
\hline
1) & $\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Method B}\\
\hline
2) & $\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you want to widen the rows `Method A` and `Method B`?

Comment: I don't understand why the methods suggested in the link you've provided wouldn't work for you. Just place the struts next to the element that's too close to an `\hline`. Using a `\multicolumn{...}{...}` should not be an impediment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cellspace` package lets you define independent minimal spacings at the top and the bottom of a cell. All you have to do then is prefixing the column to which you want to apply these minimal spacings with the letter `S`. This conflicts with the `S` qualifier from the `siunitx` package, which replaces it with the `C` prefix. It works with usual column types (l, r, c, p, m, X) – you can add column types – but not with S. See the documentation for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l Sl}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{Sc}{Method A}\\
\hline
1) & $\begin{array}{c}a ← A^Tb \\ c ← A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{Sc}{Method B}\\
\hline
2) & $\begin{array}{c}a ← A^Tb \\ c ← A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you insert "struts", i.e., elements that have height and/or depth but no width (and are thus invisible). (This idea is not original to me, by the way. It goes back, at least, to an article published by Claudio Beccari in *TeX and TUG News* in 1993.)

You place a `\Tstrut` ("top strut") on a line that follows an `\hline` and a `\Bstrut` ("bottom strut") on a line that precedes an `\hline`. If a row, such as a header row, is sandwiched between two `\hline`s, insert a `\TBstrut` ("top and bottom strut") to get better spacing.

Note that the struts defined in the example below are taller and deeper, respectively, than either `\strut` or `\mathstrut`.

If you have expressions involving fractions, be sure to place a `\Tstrut` in the numerator and/or a `\Bstrut` in the denominator, as appropriate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}         % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % "bottom" strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut}           % "top and bottom" strut

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
The strut method \TBstrut\\
\hline
$a\leftarrow A^{T}b \Tstrut$ \\ 
$c\leftarrow A^T\!d_{Z} \Bstrut$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. booktabs**

Maybe a better solution is to load `booktabs` and use the command `\addlinespace[]` to add space to individual `hline`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Method A}\\
\hline\addlinespace[2pt]  %%----> fine tune spacing
1) & $\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline\addlinespace[2pt]  %%----> fine tune spacing
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Method B}\\
\hline\addlinespace[2pt]   %%----> fine tune spacing
2) & $\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**2. tabls**

You can also use the package `tabls`, just use

```
 \usepackage{tabls}
```

in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabls}
\setlength\tablinesep{0pt}   %
\setlength\arraylinesep{0pt} % this setting mimic LaTeX but add space to the `\hline`
\setlength\extrarulesep{1pt} %

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Method A}\\
\hline
1) & $\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Method B}\\
\hline
2) & $\begin{array}{c}a\leftarrow A^Tb \\ c\leftarrow A^Td_Z \end{array}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You may further fine tune the spacing by the following commands:

```
\setlength\tablinesep{5pt} 
\setlength\arraylinesep{5pt} 
\setlength\extrarulesep{5pt}
\hline[extra]
```

In my opinion, the default works pretty well. But since ou ask for a solution that add space to the `hline`, `tabls` may be not a correct answer to your question.

As describe in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201718/9632), `tabls` also has to be loaded before the `array`-package, and then probably loose its functionality.